# What does the "for" standard for in the mvc html.LabelFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm just wondering what does the "For" in the .LabelFor or .EditorFor in the mvc html helper extension mean? I understand the parameter takes in a lambda expression but I can't work out what the "For" means?

Here is my simple cshtml file so you can see what I am looking at

```
@model MvcTest.Models.Update

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h1>Update</h1>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary()
<fieldset>
    <legend>Update profile</legend>

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)
    </div>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> > **Html.LabeFor() returns an HTML label element and the property name of the property that is represented by the specified expression.**

**For** means to bind the control with that specific **Model Property** in strongly typed views.

## For Example:

I have a model with only two properties.

```
public class MyModel
{

public string Name {get;set;}
public int Id { get; set;}

}
```

Now we create a view which is strongly typed:

```
@model AppNameSpace.Models.MyModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("MyAction","My",FormMethod.Post)) 
{

@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Name)

@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.Id)

<input type="submit" name="Save" value="Save"/>

}
```

Now in the from the model object will be posted with values of form elements in model properties.

```
public class MyController : Controller
{


  [HttpGet]
  public Action Result SomeAction()
  {

   return View();

  }

  [HttpPost]
  public Action Result SomeAction(MyModel model)
  {

   string name = model.Name;// here you will have name value which was entered in textbox

   return View();

  }

}
```

If i say:

`Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.Name)`

now when the from will be posted at the action with model , the text box value will be posted in the `Name` property whatever we have entered in the textbox. This is how strongly typed views work in asp.net mvc.

The same is the case for other **Html helpers** like `Html.LabelFor()`, `Html.HiddenFor` they are mostly used in strongly typed views, to reflect the values of from elements in action on form post of model.

For furthers detailed study,you might want to read more about Html Helpers here:

http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2009/03/03/chapter-6-understanding-html-helpers

http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/N50P050314-Understanding-HTML-Helpers-in-ASP.NET-MVC.html

https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/writing-custom-html-helpers-for-asp.net-mvc/

Comment: So when I use HiddenFor it basically means, when we post this form, the value passed into the HiddenFor will be posted with the form?

Comment: yes but it will be posted in model object as value of that specific property

Comment: @Canvas most of the time the helpers ending with For postfix are used in strongly typed views case in which you define your view model at the top of view : `@model Namespace.Models.SomeModel`

Comment: Ehsan Sajjas cheers for that, that information really cleared it up for me :)

Answer (score 1):

The for is referring to the property that you're creating it on. `@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title)` is a label for the `Title` field on the model. More specifically, it's for the [Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335710%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) that you provide it.

Comment: so basically, the "@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title)" is "we want to create a label for the model title property, and return some html for the result of the function"?